# How to resolve ambiguous layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want an iPad layout that that has two panels side by side, to fill the width of the screen and both are as tall as the screen. My attempts have led to as follows

```
self.view addConstraints:
    @"|[_sidePanel(300)]-1.0-[_mainPanel]|"
    @"V:|[_sidePanel]|"
    @"V:|[_mainPanel]|"
```

Inside __sidePanel_ I'm trying to create more constraints on child views.

Note the _sidePanel view is a UIScrollView.

I want to stack 2 views on top of one another in the side panel. 
So I add the following constraints to__sidePanel_.

```
_sidePanelView addConstraints:
    @"|[_top(300)]|"
    @"|[_bottom(300)]|"
    @"V:|[_top]-5.0-[_bottom]|"
```

It seems  I need to specify the width for these two views in order to avoid ambiguity.

But I want the bottom view to fill the remaining space of __sidePanel_. 
If I just pin __bottom_ to the bottom of __top_ (which gets a defined height at some point based on its contents) and to the bottom of its parent __sidePanel_, the __sidePanel_ and __bottom_ are both ambiguous; which makes sense i guess since the constraints are awfully similar (and which doesn't get avoided by adding the constraint for __bottom_ to the __sidePanel_ view as opposed to the topmost self.view).

If I hardcode a height for __bottom_, i resolve ambiguity but I don't want a defined height; i want it to fill remaining space in __sidePanel_.

Any suggestions on what I could try to resolve ambiguity but still achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it came down to the fact that the view I was trying to have subviews constrain to its bounds was a UIScrollView, which wasn't happening. I since changed it to a UIView and voila my constraints work. And there you have it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a height for either top or bottom -- it sounds like top gets a defined height at some point, but you need set a defined height for it **initially**, which you can change later.

Also, there's no need to specify the widths (300) for either top or bottom, since you've pinned them to the sides of sidePanel, which itself has a defined width. so these constraints worked fine with no ambiguity:

```
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_sidePanel(300)]-1.0-[_mainPanel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_sidePanel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_mainPanel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

    [_sidePanelView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_top]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [_sidePanelView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_bottom]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [_sidePanelView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_top]-5.0-[_bottom]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    self.topHeightCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.top attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:300];
    [self.top addConstraint:self.topHeightCon];
```

Later, when you calculate the actual height for top, you can use self.topHeightCon.constant = (some value) to adjust its height.

Comment: in the layout that I try to outline above, does it matter if I add the constraints for the stacked _top and _bottom views to self.view or _sidePanelView? Would that make a difference either way?

Comment: @towpse, I haven't tried that, but I suspect that it would matter. You should add the constraints to the view's superview (or to the view itself for things internal to that view, like height and width).

Comment: hey so i forgot to mention that _sidePanel was a UIScrollView. I changed it to a simple UIView and my initial constraints now work without specifying a height for either _top or _bottom.

Comment: I take it you can't easily pin a child view to both edges of a parent UIScrollView.

Comment: @towpse, yes I think so.